Minecraft Bedrock keeps crashing on PC
When I load into a world on bedrock Minecraft on my PC I can play for a few seconds, then it crashes. Its been happening for a while now. About 3 months I think.

This has happened before in many other worlds. It's possible that the save has been corrupted in a way where you can load it for a second, then it tries to load something corrupted and crashes.

Its every world ive tried. Ive even made new worlds

Oh, so everyone of your worlds have crashed your game?

Yes. Even new worlds that ive created. It's never happened before.

That's sad. Maybe uninstall and reinstall the game. That might help.

MAKE SURE TO RECOVER YOUR WORLDS BEFORE YOU DO! I should have said that in my last comment.

I'll try after school

Do you have any mods installed?

No, I dont. I rarely use mods even on java

@PenguRoxy How did everything work out?

my PC hates me and wont let me download it from the build in store and wont let me login to the mojang website

Have you tried updating your video card drivers? Did you happen to update the game or your OS before the problem started occurring? Please [edit] all relevant information into your question, including that of your former comments.

Perhaps the inability to log into the Mojang site is an underlying problem?

It happned before i couldnt log into the Mojang site

There have been a few other really well known games that bug out on PC. For instance, the Sims 4, where the body texture glitches out, everyone's sims are fat, and their eyes are red. That bugs only happened, on PC, and not Mac. No saying that is the issue, just hoping that someone with higher intelligence (probably like Joachim) can use that information to figure something out.

Something just came to me. I asked AI if the bedrock files are still on the file system even after deleting the game, and it sounds like they might still be there. If so, check the logs and send a screenshot. Maybe it will hit us.

I think as this stands, there isn't enough details to troubleshoot this.  Some sort of crash log information would probably be a good thing to include.  But at the moment, this is a broad "my world crashes after a few seconds" type question with no other information for us to go off of.

i dont get any crash logs
